# how to bypass login screen and move to home screen using hive flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

how to bypass login screen and move to home screen using hive flutter

I'am trying to bypass from main file but how to store user credentials from hive and bypass if user is logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

Store user credentials in Hive: Use the Hive package to store the user credentials, such as username and password, after the user logs in.

Check for user credentials on app start: In the main.dart file, check if the user credentials are stored in Hive and navigate to the home screen if they are. If the user credentials are not stored, navigate to the login screen.

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Hive.openBox('user'),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (Hive.box('user').isEmpty) {
              return LoginScreen();
            } else {
              return HomeScreen();
            }
          } else {
            return LoadingScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are going with this approach, You may use `snapshot.data` instead of `Hive.box('user')`.